# add function is not working properly in Polynomial using linked list

Tags: linked-list

I can't find any error in this code, please can anyone help me out with this.
please provide the whole code by debugging the given code.
I'm having a problem in adding two polynomials otherwise everything is fine.
I wasted my whole week in figuring out this bug but can't be able to find it.
so I will be happy if anyone can help me, please

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
struct Node
{
int coeff;
int exp;
struct Node *next;
} *poly = NULL, *poly2 = NULL;

void create()
{
struct Node *t, *last = NULL;
int num, i;
printf("Enter number of terms");
scanf("%d", &num);
printf("Enter each term with coeff and exp\n");
for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    t = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    scanf("%d%d", &t->coeff, &t->exp);
    t->next = NULL;
    if (poly == NULL)
    {
        poly = last = t;
    }
    else
    {
        last->next = t;
        last = t;
    }
}
}
void create2()
{
struct Node *t, *last = NULL;
int num, i;
printf("Enter number of terms");
scanf("%d", &num);
printf("Enter each term with coeff and exp\n");
for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    t = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    scanf("%d%d", &t->coeff, &t->exp);
    t->next = NULL;
    if (poly2 == NULL)
    {
        poly2 = last = t;
    }
    else
    {
        last->next = t;
        last = t;
    }
}
}

void Display(struct Node *p)
{
while (p)
{
    printf("%dx%d +", p->coeff, p->exp);
    p = p->next;
}
printf("\n");
}
long Eval(struct Node *p, int x)
{
long val = 0;
while (p)
{
    val += p->coeff * pow(x, p->exp);
    p = p->next;
}
return val;
}
void add(struct Node *p, struct Node *q)
{
struct Node *sum = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
while (p && q)
{
    if (p->exp > q->exp)
    {
        sum->exp = p->exp;
        sum->coeff = p->coeff;
        p = p->next;
        if (p)
        {
            sum->next = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
            sum = sum->next;
        }
    }
    else if (p->exp < q->exp)
    {
        sum->exp = q->exp;
        sum->coeff = q->coeff;
        q = q->next;
        if (q)
        {
            sum->next = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
            sum = sum->next;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        sum->exp = p->exp;
        sum->coeff = p->coeff + q->coeff;
        q = q->next;
        p = p->next;
        if (p && q)
        {
            sum->next = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
            sum = sum->next;
        }
    }
}
while (p)
{
    sum->next = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    sum = sum->next;
    sum->exp = p->exp;
    sum->coeff = p->coeff;
    p = p->next;
}
while (q)
{
    sum->next = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    sum = sum->next;
    sum->exp = q->exp;
    sum->coeff = q->coeff;
    q = q->next;
}
sum->next = NULL;
Display(sum);
}
int main()
{

create();
create2();
Display(poly);
//printf("\n");
Display(poly2);
//printf("\n");
add(poly, poly2);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can see that there are some major issues in the code like: from 'main' you are calling create() and create(2) with poly parameters but in the function definition itself no parameter is used. So correct them first. And also maintain the proper indentation , it helps us to read the code faster.

Comment: corrected that bug.........but the previous problem(add function not working) still exists

Comment: You should precise what exactly means  _"I'm having a problem in adding two polynomials"_ . Wrong result ? Error message ? Crash ?

Comment: @MayankSinghNegi there are some flaws in the logic of your add() function. First and foremost: you want to store the new polynomial in a new linked-list 'sum' but you are updating the list header after every iteration. The header must be fixed and you should use some other node pointer(e.g. node* temp) to iterate. Otherwise upon returning the 'sum' pointer it will only point to the lastly added value

Comment: @AnkushPandit thanks sir, got the flaw in the logic of add() function. Now it worked fine. Once again a big thanks

Comment: @Zilog80 actually it was printing only the last term of sum linked list but now the problem is solved, thanks to the StackOverflow community